# Can't connect to Azure SQL server on production server

Tags: sql, azure

I have been using an Azure SQL db for months in development with no issues. I've created an api using JS, Express and Tedious. Today I moved my code to the production server. I made sure the new server API is added to the firewall. But I'm getting the following error when the api tries to connect to Azure:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to
> s********s.database.windows.net:1433 in 15000ms

The connection still works in development and I'm able to access the db from SQL Server Management Studio. The config information is the same in dev as production.

I'm not sure where to go for troubleshooting from here. What could be different by moving it into production? Any troubleshooting suggestions?

EDIT/ADDITIONAL INFO:

I have my db config stored in a file that is used for all of my calls to sql. Here is an example of some of the code that makes the sql call:

```
    var config = require("./dbconfig");
    const sql = require("mssql");

    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    var myproc = new sql.Request(pool);
    myproc.input("userEmail", sql.VarChar(75), userEmail);
    let user = await myproc.execute("getUser");
    return user.recordset[0];
```

The dbconfig file looks like this:

```
const config = {
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    server: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_DB,
    options: {
        Encrypt: true,
        enableArithPort: true
    },
    port: 1433
}
```

Comment: *"The config information is the same in dev as production."* I doubt that. If this was the case, your prod environment would be on the same server and same database. Are you using Azure Key Vault to store the SQL Connection String?

Comment: Filburt, thanks for the quick reply. I should have been more specific. I have a file which stores the configuration which I require in the JS code that is doing the call to SQL. That file is the same on both the production and dev server. My next step is to connect to the production db. In order to eliminate differences, I'm just trying to connect to the development DB that lives in Azure and is a duplicate of the production db. So my config for the db is the same for the dev server as it is for the production server right now. I am not using Azure Key Vault.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a timeout (15 second failure), so something in networking.

Is your API server in Azure?

If YES, did you set "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server" to Yes (under the server's networking)?

If NO, are you sure your client IP rule is set correctly?

Comment: Thank you, Tony, for the follow up. My api is not on Azure. I believe I have my IP set correctly. I set it up by going to the Azure portal, clicking on the database, then choosing Set Server Firewall. There I added my server IP (quadruple checked the number!) Those were the steps I used to get the development server to work. For production, I'm using a VPS provided by InMotion hosting. Not sure if I need to do something differently for a VPS server?